# Difference between two different declarations with new operator and pointer

Tags: c++, new-operator

What is the difference between:

```
int* a = new int[w];

int** b= new int*[w];
```

and what exactly does this mean: `int*[w]` and `int[w]`?

Comment: Remember that `w` has to be defined as a const and not as a variable.

Comment: @RoiHatam: Are you sure?  Inside a function, I don't think that's true; a variable size is allowed.  G++ (7.1.0) allows it at file scope (`int w = 6; int *a = new int[w]; int **b = new int*[w];`), even with `g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic …`.  That's not the same as claiming "the C++ standard allows it", but the `-pedantic` should trigger a warning (error because of `-Werror`) if it is in contravention of the standard.

Comment: We are not a tutoring site. What **specifically** is unclear?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Wouldn't that be a VLA which are not supported by C++? gcc is a bad reference for standard compliance in default mode, because it has extensions enabled.

Comment: @Olaf: If the code was: `int w = 6; int vla_a[w]; int *vla_b[w];` then you'd be playing with VLAs, and that is not allowed by the C++ standard but G++ does allow it unless you specify `-pedantic`.  As it stands, with the `new`, you're allocating a dynamic array with a dynamic size — the analogue of `int *a = malloc(w * sizeof(int));` in C.  Variable sizes are allowed in `int *a = new[w];`, I'm practically certain.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks, I was not sure. Modern C++ is not really my world (It's on my todo-list - somewhere).

Comment: @Olaf: I sympathize.  There's an element of 'tentativity' in my comments because I'm not as au fait with C++11 onwards as I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* a = new int[w]
```

This first example dynamically allocates `w` integers.

```
int** b = new int*[w]
```

The second example dynamically allocates `w` pointers to integers.

Comment: And second one simply can be used to implement n-D array, as each element of array is a pointer to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you're dynamically creating an array of `int` with `w` elements.  In the second, you create an array of `int *` with `w` elements.

The notations `int*[w]` and `int[w]` are the types mentioned above: an array of `int *` of size `w`, and an array of `int` of size `w` respectively.

Comment: int** b= new int*[w]; 
Are we not creating a 2d matrix in this case with int pointers w?

Comment: @Alex: No; you are not creating a 2D matrix.  You are creating an array of pointers to `int`.  If you initialize each of those pointers to point to an array of `int`, then you can treat it more or less as a 2D array — but it still isn't a 2D array (matrix).

Comment: @Alex Technically, no.  A matrix has a fixed number of rows and columns.  The pointers are not initialized, so you need to allocate an array for each one.  These sub arrays can be of different sizes.  Also, the array of pointers and each array of ints are separate from each other, while a true 2D array is contiguous.